# Do I Need to Pull From Github Before Pushing the Project From Another Machine?

Tags: github

I am working on a project that is located on two different machines. The code has some differences because one is in development and one is already being hosted on my ubuntu machine.

If I do work on the development machine and I want to work on another machine after making changes to my repository, it gives me an error telling me that all changes cannot be committed unless I do a pull, but I am afraid to pull for fear of making any changes to my current project that I am trying to save.

So here is my question: If I pull from Github to my Ubuntu production server, after making changes on the development, is it going to add files to my production copy? Hoping someone can help me understand this. Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is.  This is standard git behavior, no?

Comment: I don't want to make any changes to my development server project; I just want to push it to Github. (to save it) The problem is that it's asking me to pull before allowing me to push all my changes since, I guess, I last pushed the project from another machine. I am afraid that pulling it is going to ruin the changes I've made, which includes deleting a lot of apps inside a Django project.

Comment: Close enough. God bless you. :)